# Image on asp.net webform disappears when detailview on same form is put into editmode

Tags: asp.net, detailsview

I have an image control on an ASP.NET web form that gets the `ImageUrl` from one of the `BoundColumn`s of a `DetailView` control on the same page. When the page loads it works fine and the image appears, but when I click edit on one of the fields in the `DetailView` and the control goes into "edit mode" the image does not display. The control is still there but the image is not. I checked to see and the `ImageUrl` at that point is still correct. I have attached the code.

```
Protected Sub DetailsView1_DataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.DataBound
    Image1.ImageUrl = ""
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(DetailsView1.Rows(14).Cells(1).Text) Then
        Image1.ImageUrl = "~/App_Themes/Light/Images/" & DetailsView1.Rows(14).Cells(1).Text
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub DetailsView1_ModeChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles DetailsView1.ModeChanged
    If DetailsView1.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
        DropDownList1.Visible = False
        Image1.Visible = False
    ElseIf DetailsView1.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.Edit Or DetailsView1.CurrentMode = DetailsViewMode.ReadOnly Then
        DropDownList1.Visible = True
        Image1.Visible = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I checked with your code and it is working fine.

Comment: There must be something else wrong then, as the image does not display.

Comment: You can debug in firebug, why image is not displaying even with correct url, if you have not done already.